# Change value in column in a dataFrame to another value, if conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a a csv-file that has as separator the comma sign and at the same time values are separated by ".

I would love to change the value of the column ISIN  of the dataframe in Pandas to "Cash" when the original value is "-" or when the value does not exist like in the example below. How can I do this?

I copied and pasted the sample.csv file which looks as follows:

```
Emittententicker,Name,Anlageklasse,Gewichtung (%),Kurs,Nominale,Marktwert,Nominalwert,Sektor,ISIN,Börse,Standort,Marktwährung
"AAPL","APPLE INC","Aktien","3,63","123,54","1.722.459","212.792.585","212.792.584,86","IT",,"NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"MSFT","MICROSOFT CORP","Aktien","3,08","245,71","735.512","180.722.654","180.722.653,52","IT","-","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"AMZN","AMAZON COM INC","Aktien","2,38","3.187,01","43.863","139.791.820","139.791.819,63","Zyklische Konsumgüter ","-","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"GOOG","ALPHABET INC CLASS C","Aktien","1,24","2.404,61","30.223","72.674.528","72.674.528,03","Kommunikation","US02079K1079","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
```

Comment: `df['ISIN'] = df['ISIN'].replace({'-':'Cash', np.nan:'Cash'})`

Comment: @Brendan Thank your for the fast reply, works perfeclty!

Comment: another option for your case is to use the `na_values` argument to [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to treat the `'-'` character as a NaN. Then you could simply do `df['ISIN'] = df['ISIN'].fillna('Cash')`.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Ty, sounds logical and comprehensible.